# Saving plots in r in layers for PowerPoint

Tags: r, save, powerpoint, layer

I'm looking for the easiest way to save plots in R in a way that will allow me to later gradually present parts of the plot using PowerPoint animations. Is this possible to do in the saving stage at R? I tried rvg but some of the functions didn't work so looking for something simpler.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share some reproducible code of what you are trying to achieve. Are you using base R plotting, `ggplot2` or something else?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I'm using ggplot2 but the code is a bit complicated to save each layer separately. I thought there might be an easier way using some sort of save command, but I guess not :/ Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `ggplot2` you can add each layer step by step and save
the result after each step using `ggsave()`

```r
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) + geom_line()
g
```

[image]

```r
ggsave("layer1.png")
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
g + geom_line(aes(date, pce), color = "blue")
```

[image]

```r
ggsave("layer2.png")
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```